# Decrypting Encrypted Micro SD Card without phone

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, data-recovery, encryption

Since the release of the new Android version, has anyone had any success with decrypting the contents of a Micro SD card without the use of the phone?

I want to encrypt my card incase I lose the phone. However, I also don't want to be in a situation where something could happen and I am left with no way to retrieve contents from the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the purpose is to allow any decryption of the SD card without using the phone were it was encrypted. Or you could just add specific files to the cloud so that you don't have to worry about retrievable situations, in most cases people tend to use the cloud for photos and video, especially with the space it gobbles up, having 16gb 60gb worth of files on an SD card is pretty risky vs storing it in the cloud, but to answer your question you need to find it the encryption specifically serves the purpose of preventing the decryption unless the content is being decrypted from that parochial device