# Decrypting microSD card on another Android device or desktop computer

Tags: security, external-sd, encryption

I'm looking for a solution that would allow to encrypt external microSD card with the following conditions:

- external microSD card is *not* merged with the internal storage;
- encrypted external microSD is mounted upon booting automatically;
- content of an encrypted microSD card can be viewed in *another* Android device and Windows/Linux PC if the smartphone where this card has been used was physically destroyed beyond repair.

The motivation behind these criteria stems from my workflow on a desktop computers.
All of them have both system and storage drives fully encrypted with [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).
I set them up in a way that I enter a password upon booting once, and all the favorite volumes are automatically mounted and I boot into fully functioning system.
On the other hand, if for some reason I cannot boot anymore (e.g. missing or corrupted system drive), I can take off the encrypted data drive, plug it into any other machine running Windows/Linux/MacOS with installed VeraCrypt and decrypt my files in no time.

However, I cannot achieve the same with the default encryption offered by Android.
To encrypt the SD card, one must merge it with the internal memory, and if the device fails to start, there is no easy way to recover/decrypt my data from the external card.

I searched Google Play and couldn't find any third-party app similar to VeraCrypt.

There are related topics, but I couldn't find an answer in any of these either:

- [Decrypting Encrypted Micro SD Card without phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155497/decrypting-encrypted-micro-sd-card-without-phone)
- [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage)
- [How to decrypt a microSD card after a factory reset of the device used to encrypt it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116750/how-to-decrypt-a-microsd-card-after-a-factory-reset-of-the-device-used-to-encryp)

I'm using a rooted Moto G5s running Android 8.1, but a vendor-independent answer would be more preferable.

Comment: Are you looking for a non-root solution or just for rooted devices?

Comment: maybe here is what you looking for? https://alternativeto.net/software/luks/?platform=android
android is basically linux. you can compile your own static binaries for arm architecture with Linux Deploy
https://www.google.com/search?q=cryptsetup+android

Comment: @alecxs Personally, I all the devices I use are *rooted*. If the there is a solution for the non-rooted smartphones the community can benefit from, this would be ideal.

Comment: @alecxs I've been thinking about LUKS and I even used an app called *LUKS Manager* (or something similar) around 2012-2013, but then the development was seized. I'm also not sure how robust using LUKS on Android would be, e.g. I suspect a lot of things might break if I decide to upgrade to the next Android version, or flash another ROM; feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: as long as you keep all your scripts and binaries together, it should be possible to adapt. common init.d folders are `/data/adb/post-fs-data.d` `/su/su.d` and for executable binaries `/data/adb/magisk` `/su/xbin`

Comment: @alecxs This sounds quite complicated to me. Also, I don't know how to handle LUKS-encrypted volumes under Windows; programs such as FreeOTFE, LibreCrypt or DoxBox all appear to be abandonware. However, if there is no easier solution you can think of, free to post an answer (probably elaborate a bit more on a scripting side).

Comment: from VeraCrypt site: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.edslite

Comment: If you have a rooted phone, `EncFS` is a simple solution that I have been using on my K and L devices for years to use (physically) external SD card as public external storage (/sdcard) by Disabling Internal Memory (DIM). Also it's quite easy to do incremental backup of some encrypted directories like DCIM to cloud (such as with rclone). It does have multi-platform support. All you need is a kernel with FUSE support, an `encfs` binary and an `init.d` script.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Interesting, I've never heard of EncFS before. I did a brief research and it looks like one requires to use Cryptonite app for managing encrypted volumes with FUSE, but it's been taken down from Google Play. As for the kernel support, I should look deeper into what is offered for my Moto G5s. In the meantime, feel free to post an answer based on your comment – just probably add some more details, if possible, or just describe your use-case for newbies:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any GUI solutions that fit your needs but can share something about working CLI solutions.

**DISK ENCRYPTION:**

> external microSD card is not merged with the internal storage

You are talking about Android's [Adoptable Storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable). Actually it's not merged (like in case of [LVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management#EXTENT)), it's just decrypted and mounted as a separate filesystem. Android starts [emulating](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526) `/sdcard` from `/mnt/expand/[UUID]` which otherwise is from `/data/media/`. Additionally some apps are also [movable](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214568/218526) to this newly *adopted* storage. In case of [FDE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) (based on `dm-crypt`), key is stored at `/data/misc/vold/expand_*.key`, which can be used to mount the SD card on any OS running Linux kernel (including Android). All that you need is [`dmsetup`](https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html?m=1). See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145446/218526) for details.

> content of an encrypted microSD card can be viewed in another Android device and Windows/Linux PC

In case of Adaptable Storage you can backup the master key to some safe location so that it could possibly be used in case device is wiped or no more bootable. Or if you don't want to go with Android's native encryption, you can manually setup `dm-crypt` FDE (plain / LUKS) on SD card using [`cryptsetup`](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/home).

**FILESYSTEM ENCRYPTION:**

Recent versions of Android mostly use [FBE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) which is based on Linux [filesystem-level encryption](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/filesystems/fscrypt.html) (for `ext4` and `f2fs`). It doesn't use a single key, instead the master key generates per file keys on the go. On Android encrypted master keys are saved to `/data/misc/vold/user_keys/`. Device Encrypted (DE) and Credential Encrypted (CE) storages make it further complicated. Also FBE with Adoptable Storage doesn't work on Nougat and Oreo, and [doesn't look very stable](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable#fixing-double-encryption) on Pie. So it's not a very reliable option at the moment.

It's also possible to manually setup FBE using [`fscrypt`](https://github.com/google/fscrypt) (or [`e4crypt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e4crypt.8.html)/[`f2fscrypt`](https://www.mankier.com/8/f2fscrypt)) tool provided that your kernel [supports](https://github.com/google/fscrypt/blob/master/README.md#runtime-dependencies) it. But again there are multiple issues with the implementation in userspace as well as in kernel space particularly related to [key management](https://patchwork.kernel.org/cover/10881911/). So it's again not a very feasible option.

`fscrypt` is most probably going to replace `ecryptfs`; another Linux kernel's native feature. It's a stacked filesystem which can encrypt any other filesystem. But `fscrypt` ([per-file encryption](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/fs/crypto/Kconfig#13)) *“is more memory efficient since it avoids caching the encrypted and decrypted pages in the page cache”*. You can use `ecryptfs` too on Android if kernel is built with `CONFIG_ECRYPT_FS`.

**FUSE-BASED ENCRYPTION:**

All of the options discussed above are native to Linux kernel, so won't (or at least very badly) work on Windows (sorry I have no experience with Mac). However you can go for FUSE-based solutions which have more or less support on Windows as well. E.g. [`encfs`](https://github.com/vgough/encfs) and [`gocryptfs`](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs) are stackable cryptographic filesystems; more useful in situations like [incremental backups](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/file-backup-terminology-what-do-terms-differential-incremental-mean-and-how-will-they-help-m#Increm).

If you want to stick with [`veracrypt`](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html), that also works perfect, performs even better than on Windows if combined with `dmsetup` to make use of Linux kernel's native cryptographic services.

Another FUSE-based solution [`dislocker`](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker) can decrypt Bitlocker. But FUSE over FUSE may exert performance penalty, so should be avoided with right choice of filesystem drivers.

---

> encrypted external microSD is mounted upon booting automatically

You won't find an option with graceful GUI interactions to *enter a password upon booting* because unlike Linux there is no terminal `login` or `crypttab` or `PAM`. User interaction is only possible by developing an auto-starting app, which won't be up before `zygote`/`system_server` and all (native / Java) services are fully running. Or you may try to hack Android framework's SystemUI package to get the same credentials asked through UI (in case of FDE/FBE).

A simple approach would be to put an `init.d` script or create an `init` service. This should work with any of the methods described above. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526) can be helpful. I have been using `EncFS` to extend my external storage on K and L devices (details [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=75721227&postcount=9)). SD card was mounted by an `init` service, password was saved to `/data` partition which was in turn FDE encrypted.

---

**NOTES:**

- Encryption methods described above cover all commonly used filesystems including `FAT`, `exFAT`, `NTFS`, `ext4`, `f2fs` etc.
- If not using Adoptable Storage, better create two partitions on SD card to let `vold` service mount first partition on boot. First partition can be of a few hundreds of MBs. Use second partition for encryption.
- Command line applications used for encryption are available [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/utils-data-recovery-tools-testdisk-t3709380) for Android.

**RELATED:**

- [Cross-platform compatible encryption of SD-card for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215896/218526)