# How to encrypt an SD card for android so that it can also be used on other devices?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, encryption

When encrypting the SD card via Android's encryption it makes the SD card only usable on that device.

However if that device gets lost or broken or if one would like to access the SD card from another device such as another mobile phone (maybe even with another OS than android) or a computer the SD card isn't accessible.

This is why I'd like to encrypt my SD card with some other tool than the one built into Android.

Is there such an encryption tool for Android which allows you to de- and encrypt the SD card in a way that it can also be decrypted on other devices?

It would be best if the tool also automatically prompted the user to enter the SD card password right after Android has completed the entire boot-process. This question seems to be relevant: [Cross-platform compatible encryption of SD-card for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215491/78530) but it's not about specific tools/ways.
It should be capable of encrypting Android data on the SD card, convenient to use and install (FDroid or Playstore), secure, not put the card at risk of data-loss and not slow down the phone / read/write-speeds a lot.

[Here I asked about a way to do this with Android's default SD card encryption mechanism without having to root the phone until a proper solution to this question exists](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225636/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-sd-card-without-rooting-the-android-phone).

Comment: There is another question linked inside the question you mentioned which is about specific tools/ways: [Decrypting microSD card on another Android device or desktop computer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212641/decrypting-microsd-card-on-another-android-device-or-desktop-computer)

Comment: Thanks, that Q&A you linked is helpful. However, I couldn't find any concrete steps / recommended app there. The answer only discusses different technologies to use but not a simple and easy-to-implement practical solution in the form of an (intuitive) app downloadable from Playstore or FDroid. I'll check the technologies proposed there later.

Comment: the link is still there in the comments https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.edslite

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm advanced solutions aren't for fainthearted, so there is no simple and easy-to-implement solution if you want something robust. All of the solutions provided there are practical which I have used/tested at different times for different purposes. I can provide detailed step if you choose which method you want to go with. It's a matter of compatibility with your OSes and how far you can go to implement the solution. But a simple solution is use Amdroid's built-in encryption on rooted device and keep a backup of encryption key so that SD card can be decrypted later on a PC.