# How to encrypt data in additional memory?

Tags: sd-card, poco-3

I add extra memory to my Android Phone of Poco X3

I understand it's complicated to format that extra memory as another internal and I can't really put programs over there.

But can I at least got the data over there encrypted? For example, if my internal memory is full I want to send some pics over there.

How do I do so?

Is there a way that's not too complicated?

Actually if I can install some programs on the extra memory that would be great too. Lots of programs are rarely used.

Comment: You have the choice: format your sd-card as internal, then data is encrypted or use it as portable storage, then all files are stored unencrypted. These are the choices you have. BTW. Your question is really difficult to understand, especially as you have never mentioned an sd-card.

Comment: Related: [Cross-platform compatible encryption of SD-card for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215896/218526)