# How to mount sdcard as "internal" using custom filesystem on Android 10 (root access only via adb)

Tags: adb, root-access, sd-card, file-system

How can I properly mount my SD card as "internal" (i.e. so that all apps are on it) using a custom filesystem (in my case Ext4, but I'd like to use full-disk encryption using a key that I can decrypt when putting the SD card in my laptop too, and eventually switch to a custom FUSE filesystem, so it's not an ext4-specific question)?

According to https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk, I would need to run `class_stop late_start; class_stop main` to halt all applications, mount on top of /data (I guess, any other location that should be hidden?), and restart with `class_start late_start; class_start main`. However, these commands do not exist, and don't seem to be sub-commands of `init`.

**How would I do this stop-all-apps, mount-on-/data/, start-all-apps dance from an `adb` shell?**

I have root access via `adb`, but no root access for apps. The bootloader is locked (needs to be for my banking app it seems), so I can't edit /etc/vold.fstab or any other file in /system or /vendor. I'm using /e/ os Android 10 (a fork of LineageOS).

Comment: You can't do that from `adb shell`. The `init` commands you mentioned aren't to be executed from commandline but need to be put in some `.rc` file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md#commands. They are already defined in `.rc` files by ROM developers and are executed automatically in proper sequence when you format your SD card as Adoptable (internal) Storage.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"using a custom filesystem"*. I think you are looking for something like this: [Decrypting microSD card on another Android device or desktop computer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216780/218526)

Comment: even if you manage to edit something your device would brick. modifications prevented on locked bootloader. just use android native [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) and get a copy of */data/misc/vold/expand_\*.key*

Comment: @IrfanLatif "Adoptable" storage can be stopped and started while the phone is running, IIRC, so I assumed there was a way to trigger these stop / restart events. That link to your other answer is very interesting. If I understand well, you suggest to do the mounting in `init.rc` (`dm-crypt` + `mount` or `mount` + `fscrypt` or mount a FUSE filesystem). I can't edit this file: it's on boot.img, and something in the system refuses to lock the bootloader if it's modified (e.g. I flashing a magisk'ed boot.img and locking gives a "corrupted" message, and my bank's app won't run with unlocked boot)

Comment: @IrfanLatif examples of _using a custom filesystem_: Ext4, dm-crypt + Ext4, a FUSE filesystem which I wrote myself.

Comment: @alecxs I didn't know where the key was (saw somewhere that you had to dump it from RAM, that's much better!). This would work for Ext4 + dm-crypt, but wouldn't work if I wanted to use e.g. a FUSE filesystem which I wrote myself.